# Can somebody help me understand the question from the set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Multiple choice question.

Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots A_m$ be $m$ sets such that $O(A_i)=p \forall i= 1,2,\ldots,m$ and $B_1, B_2,\ldots ,B_n$ be $n$ sets such that $O(B_i)=q \forall i= 1,2,...,n$. If $\bigcup^n_{i=0} A_i =\bigcup^n_{i=0} B_i=S$ and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly $\alpha$ number of $A_i$'s and $\beta$ number of $B_j$'s, then

1)$pm=nq$

2)$\alpha pm = \beta nq$

3)$\beta pm = \alpha nq$

4)$(pm)^\alpha = (nq)^\beta$

The answer is 3.

I don't understand what is being asked in the question and how to solve it. Can somebody help with that?

Comment: Where is this question coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, which of the statements 1 - 4 follow directly from the conditions.

You could start by determing $O(S)$: Look at $\bigcup^n_{i=0} A_i =\bigcup^n_{i=0} B_i=S$

If all $A_i$ and $B_i$ **would** be disjoint (that is, $\alpha=\beta=1$), it would be $O(S)=mp=nq$ (essentially answer 1). Now consider other $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: When it says each element of S belongs to exactly α number of Ai's and β number of Bj's. What does it mean and what does $\alpha$ and $\beta$ represent?

Comment: Exactly what is written there. If you pick a $s\in S$ at random, there are **exactly** $\beta$ indices $i_1,\ldots,i_\beta$ so that $s\in B_{i_1},\ldots,B_{i_\beta}$.